How to set WPF ComboBox width to the size of the largest item in XAML?
I have a combo box:
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Options}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption}"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>

The first item in Options will always have an item in it where option.DisplayName = string.Empty  This results in a combo box that is extremely thin, because no space is needed to show string.Empty.
Is there a way, in XAML, to auto set the width of the ComboBox to the size of the largest string in ItemsSource? I'd prefer to not measure the width of the longest item and set it in the .xaml.cs
If it matters, the Grid the ComboBox is in looks like:
    <Grid Margin="5" Height="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


You just set VerticalAlignment to stretch (the default). Define columns to position the ComboBox in the center.

AFAIK, the answer is no. The drop-down list of ComboBox will be rendered when it opens for the first time. Thus the maximum width of items is unknown until the list opens.

I'm familiar with this problem. There's really no good way around it besides setting a MinWidth for the ComboBox or just keeping its HorizontalAlignment as Stretch so that it stays a constant width. The problem is WPF won't generate (let alone measure) the width of any item in the popup until the popup has opened. You could do something extremely hacky in the form of a hidden ListBox, potentially, using the same ItemsSource and DataTemplate, but setting a manual MinWidth would be far far easier.

If you want to center the ComboBox in your layout but still want it to size automatically you can use a Grid as layout container. This way the Grid will take care to arrange your ComboBox.
Since you are already using a Grid to layout your elements, all you have to do is to define columns.
Simply create at least three columns (you can use Grid.ColumnSpan to merge columns down to a three-column row for the centered element) and place the ComboBox in the center column. Set Grid.ColumnSpan on other elements to allow them to span over the full Grid. Then set the HorizontalAlignment of the ComboBox back to HorizontalAlignment.Stretch (which is the default):
<Grid Margin="5" Height="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition /> <!-- Center column -->
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!-- The centered ComboBox element -->
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="1" />

  <!-- A TextBox element that stretches across the full Grid -->
  <TextBox Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
</Grid>

